# ERROR ITMS-90046 when trying to upload app to App Store

Tags: xcode

After converting an app to Swift 3 in Xcode 8.0 I get the error below when I try to upload the app to App Store.

> ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application
>   bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not
>   supported on iOS. Specifically, value
>   '[A]' for key
>   'application-identifier' in
>   'Payload/[B].app/____________________________' is
>   not supported. This value should be a string starting with your
>   TEAMID, followed by a dot '.', followed by the bundle identifier."

I have Googled this error message and tried different things, like deleting provisioning profiles and developer account in Xcode and downloading them again, as well as cleaning the product and restarting Xcode. The error remains.

The part I named [A] in the error message above is not the real app bundle ID but a previous app name. This was changed several App Store versions ago. I don't know where Xcode found the old ID.

Does anyone have a clue what's wrong and how I can fix it?

[image]

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you manage to fix it?